# How to grab everything between a certain XML-tag

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am currently working on something with XML and XSLT. It is part of a bigger project and part of my PhD in History, so any help is extremely welcome!

I am making a Digital Edition of a textbook and this book naturally has almost always to pages next to each other, that I want to be displayed next to each other. (I will use either bootstrap or SemanticUI for that)

So I want to "grab" LITERALLY everything that follows 
the `<pb/>` element until I reach the next `<pb/>` element

So I built a `<xsl:template/>` that transforms each tei-element `<pb/>` into a div with a certain class. My problem is that the `<div>` should range up to the next `<pb>` element.

```
<xsl:template match="tei:pb">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="class"> 
                <xsl:text>test;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                <xsl:text>text-align:right;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:text>[F.</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
            <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:element name="hr"/>
    </xsl:element>
```

The desired layout would be like the following html (without the borders etc.)

```
<div class="content">
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="test" style="width: 49%;border:solid 1px red; float:left">
    <div class="page number" style="text-align:right;"> F.29v. <hr>
    </div>
      <div class="text" style="">
        Example text
      </div>
  </div>
<div class="test" style="width:49%;border:solid 1px green;float:left;">
    <div class="page number"style="text-align:right"> F.30r <hr> </div>
      <div class="text" style="">
        Here I want the text to be displayed</div>
</div>
```

I do not really expect my code from before to do what I want it to do. The code does, as I think, exactly what it is supposed to do when written this way, but I want it to result in my example output, what do I have to change? 
(it is always 2 `<pb>` elements in each XML-file, not one or three, always two.

so in pseudo-code:

````
<xsl:template match="tei:pb and all the following elements til the next tei:pb> ```

and then transform it according to my rules

my full stylesheet: 
https://pastebin.com/99CS6n6c
````

Comment: This is very hard, if not impossible, to follow. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It looks to me as if you want to use `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="tei:pb">` in the template of the container of the `pb` and its sibling elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info for instance or any XSLT 2 or 3 tutorial on grouping.

Comment: I made sort of progress: 
Now I get everything nested, even without using ```<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="tei:pb"> ``` However, I do not get the divs on the same level but rather ```<div> content1 <div> content 2  </div> </div> ``` my current template: https://pastebin.com/3w5aEweR 

I tried grouping different orders, with and without ```<xsl:for-each.group> ``` but in no way could I get two ```<div> ``` of which the first is not containing the second ...

Comment: There's not enough information there to see where you went wrong. We need to see your code in enough detail to execute it and find the bug.

Comment: current stylesheet: https://pastebin.com/RBwrTX0R

Text sample without "real text" https://pastebin.com/4PcjBrWV

Layout that I get: https://pastebin.com/30N0sNgi

what I want is of course that each ```<div> ``` only contains its paragraph.

So that I have basically the structure ```<div class="container"> <div class="left-side"> </div> <div class="right-side"> </div> </div> ```

@MartinHonnen thanks so far! Now I'll need to figure this out!
@MichaelKay thank you, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would boil down to

```
  <xsl:template match="body">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="pb">
                <div class="test" style="width: 49%;border:solid 1px red; float:left">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </div>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pb">
      <div class="page number" style="text-align:right;">
          <xsl:text>[F.</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
          <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
          <hr/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>
```

"Full example":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//body"/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="body">
      <div class="panel-body">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="pb">
                <div class="test" style="width: 49%;border:solid 1px red; float:left">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </div>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
       </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pb">
      <div class="page number" style="text-align:right;">
          <xsl:text>[F.</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="@n"/>
          <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
          <hr/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSc

For an XSLT 2 processor you would need to spell out `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` as the identity template

```
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

With that code the fragment

```
    <body>
        <pb></pb>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
        <pb></pb>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
    </body>
```

of the input sample is transformed to the HTML fragment

```
  <div class="panel-body">
     <div class="test" style="width: 49%;border:solid 1px red; float:left">
        <div class="page number" style="text-align:right;">[F.]
           <hr>
        </div>
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
           invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
           accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
           sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
           elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
           sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
           kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </p>
     </div>
     <div class="test" style="width: 49%;border:solid 1px red; float:left">
        <div class="page number" style="text-align:right;">[F.]
           <hr>
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
           invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
           accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
           sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
           elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
           sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
           kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: wow that's extremely helpful, thanks for that! 
But I think my problem still is not solved, as the first ```<div> ``` still catches the second one, they should be on the same level, not nested inside

Comment: I am wrong. it works, Thank you very very much, you have been very helpful! 
Now I need to figure some further steps out ... But I'll get on now and ask again later!